# TFS link dropdown field to TFS Group

Tags: tfs

New to TFS, so you may need to bear with me.  I have created a new field on my Feature WIT.  I want to restrict the values in that field to the members of a group I have created.  I figured it would work by me double clicking on the field in the WIT editor in VS, clicking on the Rules tab, adding a VALIDUSER rule, and selecting the group I had created.  The issue I am having is that I don't see my group in the list.

So am I way off track on what I am trying to achieve, if so, what's the right way?  If I am almost there, what have I missed along the way?

Comment: Just a quick update - The dropdown does not list users on the project, but if I type their name in, TFS finds them.  Still can't work out how to restrict choices to the group I want to though.

Comment: Regarding ALLOWEDVALUES rule, the For dropdown should list the TFS group. If you click new, then you can type the general string (e.g. hello) to the the List Item dropdown. The screenshot shows List Item dropdown is empty, so what's your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I completely get your point, I have add a sample with follow below steps:

1. Creat a collection level group.  Team Explorer-->Team Project Collection Settings-->Group Membership-->New-->Group name: MyTeam--> Double-click [your collection]\MyTem-->select Windows User or Group-->Add-->add users
2. Create a "Feature" work item type. Tool-->Process Editor-->Work Item Types-->Open WIT from server-->Copy an existing work item type and change the name as "issue".
3. In Field tab, double-click Assigned To-->Rules-->New-->ALLOWEDVALUES-->in ALLOWEDVALUES window, click New-->in List Item Edit window, enter [Project]\MyTeam-->OK, then save this work item type.
   [image]

For test:
4. Create a new "Feature" item, in Assigned To drop down list, you can only see the users you add in MyTeam group.

***Note:*** TFS will list all the users in group instead of directly list group in the drop down. And you could restart the Sever if the changs not generated immediately.

---

**Update**

Please delete the **VALIDUSER** rule, and add **ALLOWEDVALUES** rules with which project group which you want to be displayed in Assigned To field. Please refer to the following example:

```
<FIELDS>
<FIELD name="Assigned To" refname="System.AssignedTo" type="String" reportable="dimension">
  <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="[Project]\Contributors" />
  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
</FIELD>
```

Comment: Please delete the **VALIDUSER** rule, and add **ALLOWEDVALUES** rules with which project group which you want to be displayed in Assigned To field. Please refer to the following example:

`<FIELDS>
<FIELD name="Assigned To" refname="System.AssignedTo" type="String" reportable="dimension">
  <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="[Project]\Your Group" />
  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
</FIELD>`

Comment: Hi Patrick.  Have followed your instructions to the letter (I was almost there!) but the problem I have is that I cannot use the group I have created the the "ALLOWEDVALUES" dialog.  I am trying to put together some screenshots to show you the issue.
The only difference is that I am using the TFS tools to create the group, I don't seem to have the option you describe in VS, i.e. in my Team Explorer, I don't have a Team Project Collection Settings option.

Comment: OK, I found that option in VS, and it shows me the group and member I created, so I have done the right thing.  When I get to the part where I need to add the group, there is nothing to choose from in the drop down list, and if I just type it in, when I come to save it errors saying it doesn't exist.  Let me add the screeners, show you what I mean

Comment: Names have been changed to protect the guilty, and they should probably be the other way round.  Please let me know if you can see anything I have done wrong.

Comment: Did you select the **new changed workitem type** and create a **new** work item for test? This may not work on the existent work item.

Comment: Hi Patrick.  I have created a new WIT (from an existing one) and added a new field to that, and I still get the exact same issue.  Thanks for all your help so far, BTW.